# Unable to hide keyboard on click search button in a UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

I am using a `UISearchBar` to search a list, but when I click on the search button
on the keyboard, the keyboard does not hide.
Please help me to fix this issue.
Here is my code

```
-(void)search:(UISearchBar*)searchbar Text:(NSString*)text
{
    [copyListOfItems removeAllObjects];
    if([text length] > 0) {
    //  [ovController.view removeFromSuperview];
    searching = YES;
    NSString *searchText = searchBar.text;
           for(imergencyData *objtrust in aryTrustee)
          {
          NSRange titleResultsRange = [objtrust.strName rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        if (titleResultsRange.length > 0)
            [copyListOfItems addObject:objtrust];
    }
    NSLog(@"number of object found %d",copyListOfItems.count);
}
else
    {
    //  [tblTrustee insertSubview:ovController.view   aboveSubview:self.parentViewController.view];
    [searchbar resignFirstResponder];
    searching = NO;
    //tblTrustee.scrollEnabled = NO;
}
[tblTrustee reloadData];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar
 {
       [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
       [self.view endEditing:YES];
 }

 //Method call when type text in search box
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
        [self search:theSearchBar Text:searchText];

}
//method call when on search button
-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBa{
        [searchBa endEditing:YES];
        [searchBa resignFirstResponder];
        [self search:searchBa Text:searchBar.text];

}
```

Comment: Add more description to your question with an example of your code so that people will be able to help you out.

Answer (score 4):

put  this line of code and try it once,

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)aSearchBar {
  [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
  [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

(or)
`EDIT`:

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
      [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
      [self.view endEditing:YES];
  }
```

Comment: now check it it'l works place it in searchBarTextDidEndEditing method.

Comment: No,it's not working because above delegate not calling on click of search button

Comment: once check your search bar delegate was connected or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Set first `searchbar.delegate = self` then in `- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar` call `[searchbar resignFirstRespnder]`

Good Luck

Comment: still i am using same code of line,but it's not working for me.

Comment: following code i am using- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar
{
    
 [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: Right, but don't forget to set the UISearchBar delegate in viewDidLoad

Comment: Yes i have already set delegate and it's calling delegates methods also

Comment: just put a breakpoint and check if it call this delegate method

Comment: put the following code: po theSearchBar in debug area and check if it is not nil

Comment: you can use [self.view endEditing:YES] instead :)

Comment: try this [theSearchBar endEditing:YES] it may help :)

Comment: are you in ModalViewController ??

Comment: No,it's just a simple viewcontroller where we are using search bar that's it

Answer (score 0):

You can use below delegate which is called when searchbar Search button is clicked.

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar
{    

    [theSearchBar resignFirstResponder];

 }
```

Or use this as :

```
- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar
    {    

        [self keyBoradRemove];

     }

- (void) keyBoradRemove 
{
    searchBar.text = @"";
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

here searchBar is an instance of UISearchBar.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar;
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Nishant bhai ye bhi kam nahi kar raha hai.please help

Comment: @dhiraj it should work. I assume you have done something wrong in your code. Plz check your code again.

Comment: No,Nishant it was working  some hours  before but not now, even i have already revert back my all changes.

Comment: Reset your simulator once and quit it after reset then check .

Comment: sorry nishant nothing happened

Comment: Is searchBarSearchButtonClicked delegate calling when you click search button ?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use search bar delegate as

```
     -(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
     {
       [searchBar1 resignFirstResponder];
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

> use this code for hide keyboard on click of search button of keyboard

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *) bar
{
    UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;
    NSArray *views = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0f) ? bar.subviews : [[bar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];
for (UIView *subview in views)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subview;
        break;
    }
}
searchBarTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
  {
      [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

   }
```

But before that kindly check whether you have set the search bar delegate properly.

Answer (score 0):

for swift 1.2 you can touch outside or click search , in both cases keyboard will hide

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```